# How to restrict scrolling of a mobile site but allow access to potentially retracted address bar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, mobile

*[I have a repo up and running if you're interested in contributing to solutions.](https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/angular-swipe-drawer)*

I've run into an interesting problem while constructing a mobile site.

I am setting 'overflow: hidden;' to html/body when a drawer is toggled. This is so the window can't be scrolled, and the drawer - which is scrollable - on reaching it's limits doesn't scroll the page (`e.preventDefault();` & `e.stopPropagation();` simply don't do the trick).

This all works great. Fantastic if this was a Phonegap app. However - as this is a website, the inconsistent overflow setting creates a usability issue with the browser's 'fullscreen mode'. *'Fullscreen mode' is when the address bar is hidden upon scrolling down the page. When scrolling up the bar will reappear.* When toggling the drawer the browser is essentially locked in either 'non fullscreen mode' or 'fullscreen mode'. The latter is the real issue - as users are simply unable to access the address bar - and gives the impression the browser has locked up or something weird.

Any bright ideas as to how (probably with Javascript) a scroll/touchmove could still give the effect of entering/exiting 'fullscreen mode'? I've had a play with the fullscreen API, but that's proper fullscreen, not just the address bar.

here are some screenshots:

[image: example]

1. site loads, we can see the address bar
2. site is scrollable as expected, browser enters 'fullscreen mode'
3. we toggle the drawer to open - the site is now unresponsive (besides the drawer scrolling and any gestures [via AngularJS directives] I've got to hide the drawer)
4. the drawer toggled when the address bar is visible. Good for usability, but the expected 'fullscreen mode' when using a site doesn't occur (would be nice to have the real estate).

EDIT2: https://medium.com seems to achieve what I'm after.

EDIT3: Some success with a invisible absolute positioned div sitting on top of everything - but that has it's own issues.

Comment: There is programmatic way to unhide a address bar while is hidden in mobile safari (I haven't tried other browsers). You either ended up disable fullscreen mobile by setting `height: 100%` all the time or by setting `height: 100%` when slide menu is toggled. Both have pros and cons. Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than setting `overflow: hidden;` on body when the drawer is out, how about making the drawer `position: fixed; overflow-y: auto;`, that way the user can make the choice to scroll the body to get to the address bar or the drawer.

Just out of interest, what does Firefox for Android do in this situation? It might be worth filing a bug with the Chromium team if Firefox doesn't display similar usability problems.

EDIT: I've taken a look at the code at https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/marabeas.io when running in Android Chrome and Android Firefox via their respective ADB-enabled remote debuggers (really good tools!).

I've come to the conclusion that there isn't a *nice* way to get the address bar to show once it's hidden when body has `overflow: hidden` on it.
There is however after a *hacky* way!

Shift the main scrollable area from body to a div, in this case, `#content`. Then, `position: absolute;` body and make it fill the viewport *plus some extra height* when on mobile. Given below is the relevant CSS applied on the mobile browsers:

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Then, as the browser is looking for body to be doing the scrolling as to whether or not to display the address bar, get the `#content` scroll to be linked with the main body scroll, though this may not be having an effect!:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var currentScrollTop = document.getElementById('content').scrollTop;
    if(currentScrollTop < lastScrollTop) {
        // Upwards scroll!
        document.body.scrollTop -= 10;
    } else {
        // Downwards scroll!
        document.body.scrollTop += 10;
    }
    lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
 });
```

I'm sending you a pull request now: https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/marabeas.io/pull/5

Comment: That's the current state of the drawer, unfortunately this all stems from trying to stop scrolling (touchmove) propagation when the drawer hits its limits. Point on the other browsers though. I'll have to install and have a play.

Comment: FireFox mobile completely ignores all CSS regarding overflow being hidden. Everything scrolls. I thought this was 2014, not the 90's.

Comment: Doh! Perhaps there's a JS solution to this after all. Would you mind posting your touchmove JS code so we can modify it? I'm thinking something like this in the event handler:`if(scrollHeight > drawerHeight) { return; }`

Comment: There currently is no touchmove code besides some Angular swipe directives regarding the drawer - and that's all self contained. You can see it all here: https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/marabeas.io Are you suggesting using JS rather than overflow hidden to restrict scrolling?

Comment: I'm looking into this using a clone of your repo as I also suffer from this bug in a few projects it seems. From what I've read, there doesn't seem to be a workaround to the chrome issue yet. As a side note, I'm Very impressed by angular and your work with it so far. Should you tag your question with "angularjs" too, to get more attention?

Comment: Cheers, tag should only be there if relevant... I might make the question broader rather than specifically about hidden overflow...

Comment: @Patrick I've updated my answer with a (very) hacky solution!

Comment: She ain't bad! Interestingly it's not working (address bar retraction/show) when the drawer is closed. Little worried about scrollable div support as well. I'll have a play on my 2.2 device tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

how about using document.body.scrollTop -= 1?    I don't hava a try, just a guess

Comment: Simply scrolls the document with no effect on the address bar.